# monogame - image quality after scaling

Tags: image, scaling, monogame, blurry

I am writing a GameObject class for monogame(sprite's position, alpha, rotation, ect...)

And I got a problem when i've started scaling images. Is there a way to scale images without losing quality?

Here is how I am rendering everything

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<int, GameObject> go in RenderObjects)
{
     spriteBatch.Draw(go.Value.img, go.Value.getRect(), go.Value.RenderArea, Color.White * (float)go.Value.alpha, (float)go.Value.rotation, go.Value.getCenter(), SpriteEffects.None, 0f);          
}
```

And here is what happends if you try to scale a 16x64 image to 160x640

[Click to see the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q97s1.png)

^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been messing around with monogame, and I've accidently found the solution.
You just need to add some parameters to spriteBatch.Begin();

```
spriteBatch.Begin(... , ... ,SamplerState.PointClamp);

foreach (KeyValuePair<int, GameObject> go in RenderObjects)
{
     spriteBatch.Draw(go.Value.img, go.Value.getRect(), go.Value.RenderArea, Color.White * (float)go.Value.alpha, (float)go.Value.rotation, go.Value.getCenter(), SpriteEffects.None, 0f);
}
spriteBatch.End();
```

There are actualy more ways to do it, but I don't quite understand how. Something to do with graphics.GraphicsDevice